# How to get error info from dynamic C# code compiling

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# application which uses a C# script interface. That means that my application will compile C# code and run it.

I am using the System.CodeDom.Compiler class to do it with.

The problem is that if I run the code below it throws an InvalidCastException because it is trying to cast a string to an int in my dynamic code.

If I catch the exception I have no indication where in the 'dynamic code' that error occured. For instance 'InvalidCastException on line 8'.

I get a stack trace, but no line numbers.

Any ideas? I want to present to our users enough information to know where their error is.

```
public class NotDynamicClass
{
    public object GetValue()
    {
        return "value";
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var provider = CSharpCodeProvider.CreateProvider("c#");
        var options = new CompilerParameters();
        options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("DynamicCodingTest.exe");
        var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, new[] 
        { 
@"
using DynamicCodingTest;

public class DynamicClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        NotDynamicClass @class = new NotDynamicClass();
        int value = (int)@class.GetValue();

    }
}"
        });

        var t = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("DynamicClass");
        t.GetMethod("Main").Invoke(null, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set [`IncludDebugInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.includedebuginformation%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to `true` on your `CompilerParameters`.

**Update**: At the bottom of the MSDN documentation there is a community remark:

> For C#, if you set this property to true you need to also set GenerateInMemory to false and set the value of OutputAssembly to a valid file name. This will generate an assembly and a .pdb file on disk and give you file and line number information in any stacktraces thrown from your compiled code.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it doesn't make any difference for me.

Comment: What specifically will that change to tell me the line number? Perhaps I am just not looking at the right thing.

Comment: Well, the debug information usually contain the line numbers. Another try is to add `/d:DEBUG` to the `CompilerOptions`

Comment: OK, great. I had to tell it to generate the assembly on disk as per your update above, and it worked after that.